# Convert List<T> to Map<T, U> using Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to convert a `List<T>` to `Map<T, U>` using Java 8 but I keep getting stuck at this one part. What I am trying to have is the value of the map to be of some variable of type U. Lets say for this example that `T` is a `Person` object and `U` is a `String`.

```
list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x, ""));
```

However, I keep getting the following error under `x -> x`:

```
no instance of type variable T,U exists so that String conforms to Function<? super T, ? extends U>
```

Any ideas on what the issue can be?

Comment: How did you declare the the Map variable to which you're assigning the result? Can you please show all the relevant code?

Comment: `list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x, x-> ""))`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A map is a collection of key value pairs. You mentioned that you want the keys to be instances of `Person`, but what about the values? What do you want the values to be?

If you want the values to be the person's name, then you can do:

```
list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x, Person::getName));
```

If you somehow just want all the values to be `""` (I don't think this is very useful though), you still need a lambda:

```
list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x, x -> ""));
```

It seems like you might just want a bunch of unique values, in which case you could use `Collectors.toSet`:

```
list.stream().collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Or just `distinct`:

```
list.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: If, like Sweeper suggests, you want all values to be `""` - that looks like you only want to work with unique keys, which sounds like a `Set<Person>`

Comment: @NigelNop It could be. But now that I think about it, OP might want a map with meaningless values because they want to fill the map afterwards.

Comment: that sounds strange though - OP would need to recompute the keys anyways to insert the values